# "in Figure 1 to Figure 3" or "in from Figure 1 to Figure 3"

Tags: phrases, prepositions

I have 3 figures to demonstrate some process. Which one should be used?

> The process is shown in Figure 1 to Figure 3.

or

> The process is shown in from Figure 1 to Figure 3.

I feel that the first one is more natural. Or should we use

> The process is shown in Figures 1 to 3.

**Edit**

What if the # of figures is more than 10? Is there any succinct representation?

Comment: "in figures 1, 2, and 3"

Comment: @HotLicks Is "in figures 1 - 3" appropriate?

Comment: Certainly, except possibly in stuffily formal publications.

Answer (score 2):

How about: **The above process is shown/ is demonstrated in the figures: 1, 2, 3**

**edit**

**The above process is shown from the figure 1 to figure 20** or ***from figure 1-20**

Comment: What if there are many figures (say 20)? Is there any succinct representation?